# Is it possible to get XSS without event handlers inside <img> Payload?

Tags: xss

I am pentesting a super strange website and was trying to get Stored XSS on their main website. After some hours of testing i found that it is possible to inject sucesfully without any encoding:

```
<img src="any" alt="any">
```

Cool right? the thing is i have tried +50 event handlers (some of them not even working for images) and 80% of them were blocked by the waf and the rest that were accepted (code 200 instead of 500) but were stripped from the response, even invalid ones. So

```
<img src="any" asdasd=asdasd alt="any"> Turns into --> <img src="any" alt="any">
```

So i was wondering, is there any possible way to exploit this without event handlers?

i know that  isn't allowed for most browsers and will not trigger anything (correct me if I'm wrong here).

Comment: My answer here may be helpful, but you are probably hosed. Sounds like they are properly parsing and processing HTML. Skip to the part about a robust parser: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220447/security-risks-of-user-generated-html/220462#220462

Comment: forgot to say but because jkksjdbf=ksjdfsd gets filtered they probably use a whitelist instead of a blacklist to filter handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try other payloads for XSS?

Here's the cheat-sheet: https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/cheat-sheet

You can check the Event, Compatibility, tag as well as code there.

If 80% percent were blocked by WAF, you need to bypass it, some bug bounty hunters already bypass some WAF and here's the link:

https://github.com/EdOverflow/bugbounty-cheatsheet/blob/master/cheatsheets/xss.md

For the browser, just test in all browsers.

Comment: they use a whitelist, i know that because i tried to add sjkldnf=ksjnfsdf as event hanlder and was stripped from the response.

Comment: you are working in the image only? or try something like 

`<iframe src=javascript:alert(1)>`

For no event handlers, check here:

https://brutelogic.com.br/blog/xss-without-event-handlers/

Comment: thanks, that was useful! but didn't work unfortunately.