# XSS payloads getting filtered but HTML tags are getting rendered. Can we exploit this?

Tags: xss, javascript, html

I was trying to test a potential XSS vulnerability on a website. On the search bar I can see the filtering process happening i.e if I type `script>` (not with starting `<`) I can see the same in the searching column just below the search bar, but when I type `<script>` it shows the output as removed. I have tried many XSS payloads but none of them is working. Though HTML tags are being executed. Can someone help me with bypassing the filter?

Hey, Thanks a lot for the replies here are all the things which I have tried till now in detail:

The app has a search bar in which we can search for things and just below the search bar there is a text box that in real-time shows the text we have written. For example, if I search for tea the text box below the search bar will display "showing results for tea".

Now here I tried to input a basic XSS payload that is , whenever I am typing the whole payload with syntax() the search bar just filters it and the text box below shows (" ") empty string. By this, I can confirm that the app is filtering basic payloads like . I tried bypassing it by using the <script> method but the output comes as Scrremovedipt.

I tried javascript payloads and many more but none of them works but HTML code gets rendered.  By this I mean if I type (`<h1>tea</h1`) the text box renders and shows the output. I also tried the
`<iframe src="domain/exploit.html"></iframe>` and it works. But the issue with this is whenever I click on submit button the server filters all the syntax due to which the HTML code also fails.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Security risks of user generated HTML?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220447/security-risks-of-user-generated-html)

Comment: This is pure programming question and is off topic here.

Comment: I disagree @mentallurg if XSS is off-topic in your mind you really need to reconsider a lot in the information security profession. There is no reason answers can link to or describe XSS methodologies when WAF/sensitisation exist. AlphaNumeric please update your question to show what you tried and what was filtered out, specificly what you XSS vectors you have tried yourself that failed. be very descriptive and explain more about what has thwarted your attempts so far or the question is far too vague and many people will be hostile to you. BTW Welcome!

Comment: This is on-topic, but too general to give you concrete help. Without any hints about the filter's inner workings, we could just suggest you keep trying with different attack vectors.

Comment: Agreed with @Arminius; if you want us to help with this, you need to provide more detailed information of 1. what you've tried so far, including which tags have "worked" (there are *so many* ways to get XSS), and 2. what the app does when you try exploits, in as much detail as possible (is it making server requests, and if so what's in the responses? is it doing the filtering client-side, and if so what's in the filter function? etc.)

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot for the reply I have updated the details please have a look

Comment: @Stof: XSS is relevant as long as concepts and principles are discussed. But what the author describes is pure programming question. And programming questions - even if they are about XSS - are off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to check if cache is enabled by intercepting the traffic with Burp Suite. Check if you can use  cache poisoning to inject JavaScript. Tested some on labs but it's worth looking at in real apps. You could check Portswigger for info on cache poisoning. You could also read Web App Hackers book by Daffyd Stufford.

Hope that helps.  ✌

Answer (score 0):

If iframes are allowed in general, there are at least four things that immediately suggests trying:

1. inline event handlers (`onload`, etc.) as HTML attributes on the iframe tag. Of course, you can do these with any element, not just iframes.
2. javascript: URI as the iframe `src` value. This is basically equivalent to injecting a small `<script>` tag; the code that comes after `javascript:` is treated as JS and executes in the parent page's context.
3. data: URI as the iframe `src` value. Data URIs can store entire documents (or arbitrary other data), but because they don't set their own origin, they generally inherit the parent's origin. Therefore, a bare-bones HTML doc with an inline script will execute the script in the parent's context.
4. Malicious document in the iframe's `srcdoc` attribute. Srcdoc is a relatively little-used attribute that somebody trying to strip malicious attributes might not know about. Otherwise, this is the same as #3.

So, that's four potential attacks from a single element. I hope you now realize why nobody is going to give you a comprehensive list of things to try, or even going to try giving you a lot of steps to try without more information. There's just too many options!

---

With all that said...

> the issue with this is whenever I click on submit button the server filters all the syntax due to which the HTML code also fails

It's really not clear what you're saying here, but it sounds like possibly the server is rejecting search URLs that have any HTML in them? In that case, unless there's some way to send the request such that the client-side loading is done (as when searching) but the server-side checking isn't, you only have a **self-XSS**, which is generally quite pointless. There might be such a way - for example, does the URL fragment (the part after `#`) contain the search query as it gets built? The fragment isn't sent to the server, but can be parsed client-side, so that *might* be a way to get DOM-based XSS (the script parses the search query and injects it into the DOM rather than (re)loading a whole page from the server).

Alternatively, you might be able to bypass the filter on the server. There are in fact a lot of ways to get XSS, provided you're allowed to use the `<` and `>` characters. Even if you're not, sometimes Unicode look-alikes for them get converted into those characters, server-side via "punycode" or similar, *after* the anti-XSS filtering. Finally, maybe the user content is injected or reflected somewhere other than text, such as inside another HTTP attribute or script, so all you need to do is e.g. break out of a string.